# How to kill a CodeMirror instance?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm using Codemirror v3.16 and I'm trying to figure out how I can kill an instance of my codemirror? Basically codemirror fires when a textarea opens in a modal on my page. Closing this modal, I need to kill the instance, else when I reopen the modal, I get two textareas.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the CodeMirror instance was created with `CodeMirror.fromTextArea`, you can use its `toTextArea` method to copy the current contents to its "mirrored" text area and remove the instance.

Assuming your CM instance has the id of "CMEditor":

```
CM = document.getElementById('CMEditor');
CM.CodeMirror.toTextArea();
```

Alternately, you could instantiate the CM instance outside of the modal, and just hide and show it when the modal opens.

Comment: Hi I am getting `.toTextArea() is not a function` can you please help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 12):

When CodeMirror is removed from the DOM (and you kill all existing references to it that JavaScript might be holding), it'll be garbage collected. There is no explicit 'kill' method, you simply stop referring to it.

Comment: Chrome's memory profiler would like to disagree with you. DOM node references made by closures don't magically disappear just because those nodes were removed from the DOM. If CodeMirror stores its instances in the global CodeMirror object, you have memory leaks.

Comment: Which it doesn't, so I really don't know what you are talking about here.

Comment: My case is a one page application where you're constantly creating and destroying CodeMirror textareas. Are you saying this would do? https://jsfiddle.net/7zvnyagq/

Comment: Marijn, I guess Doidgey's question (the "OP") was really meant to be about how "CodeMirror is removed from the DOM".

Answer (score 11):

Answers above only work for CM on top of textarea which is not always the case. This is better:

```
cm.setOption("mode", "text/x-csrc");
cm.getWrapperElement().parentNode.removeChild(cm.getWrapperElement());
cm=null;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10681153)

Comment: huh ? the OP asked 'how I can kill an instance of my codemirror' and I have shown code to do just that

Comment: Is `cm.setOption("mode", "text/x-csrc");` really needed?

Comment: Hi I am trying this and this seems to remove even the `textarea` for me. I am unable to see the textarea as well. Am I doing something wrong here? Some suggestion please.

Answer (score 5):

The version 5.3 or 05/2015 Update

```
CM = document.getElementById('CMEditor');

CM.CodeMirror.toTextArea(); // is not working 

CM.toTextArea(); // is making the magic happen
```

Comment: Hi I tried this and its throwing me `.toTextArea is not a function` in the latest version. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I've added the above code to run when the modal is closed, but it says that --- cmeditor.toTextArea is not a function

```
$("body").on("hidden.bs.modal", ".modal", function()
{
    $(this).removeData("bs.modal");

    cmeditor = document.getElementById("email_template_text");
    cmeditor.toTextArea();
});
```